# Assemble multiple .csv (python)

Tags: python, csv

I have several .csv's with names like:

```
 "15526 - Afjuej_djqu3z.pdf-1.csv":
 "15526 - Afjuej_djqu3z.pdf-2.csv":
 "15526 - Afjuej_djqu3z.pdf-2.csv"
 "15526 - Afjuej_djqu3z.pdf-4.csv"
....
```

15526 - Afjuej_djqu3z.pdf-1.csv contain:

```
,Élément,État général,Observations
0,Quais,État d'usage,
1,QuaisQuais 2Quais 3

Quais 4,,
```

15526 - Afjuej_djqu3z.pdf-2.csv contain:

```
,Élément État général,Observations
0,Entrepôt,
1,Dalle beton État d'usage,
2,,
3,Entrepôt / Dalle beton Entrepôt / Dalle beton,Entrepôt / Dalle beton
4,,
5,Entrepôt / Dalle beton,Entrepôt / Dalle beton
6,Murs État d'usage Quelques trous d’exploitation,
7,Bardage avec impacts,
8,Demande preneur : ouverture de la cellule sur mur,
9,maçonne et rideau adjacent,
10,,
11,Entrepôt / Murs Entrepôt / Murs,Entrepôt / Murs
```

15526 - Afjuej_djqu3z.pdf-3.csv contain:

```
,Entrepôt,Unnamed: 0,Unnamed: 1
0,Élément,État général,Observations
1,Entrepôt / MursEntrepôt / MursEntrepôt / Murs

Entrepôt / MursEntrepôt / MursEntrepôt / Murs,,
```

........
I would like to assemble them into one .csv **in order** and name it "15526-Afjuej_djquz_assemble.csv" for example.

```
,Élément,État général,Observations
0,Quais,État d'usage,
1,QuaisQuais 2Quais 3

Quais 4,,
,Élément État général,Observations
0,Entrepôt,
1,Dalle beton État d'usage,
2,,
3,Entrepôt / Dalle beton Entrepôt / Dalle beton,Entrepôt / Dalle beton
4,,
5,Entrepôt / Dalle beton,Entrepôt / Dalle beton
6,Murs État d'usage Quelques trous d’exploitation,
7,Bardage avec impacts,
8,Demande preneur : ouverture de la cellule sur mur,
9,maçonne et rideau adjacent,
10,,
11,Entrepôt / Murs Entrepôt / Murs,Entrepôt / Murs
,Entrepôt,Unnamed: 0,Unnamed: 1
0,Élément,État général,Observations
1,Entrepôt / MursEntrepôt / MursEntrepôt / Murs

Entrepôt / MursEntrepôt / MursEntrepôt / Murs,,
```

I don't know why but pd.concat doesn't work:

```
Unnamed: 0,Élément,État général,Observations,Représentant le mandataire,Unnamed: 0.1,Bureau,Unnamed: 1,Cage d’escalier,Entrepôt,Remise des clefs,Élément État général
0,Quais,État d'usage,,,,,,,,,
1,QuaisQuais 2Quais 3,,,,,,,,,,
Quais 4,,,,,,,,,,,
0,,,,,,,,,,,
1,,,,Adresse e-mail : ,,,,,,,
0,Radiateur,,,,Non fonctionnel,,,,,,
1,,,,,,,,,,,
2,,Bureau / Radiateur,,,Bureau / Radiateur,,,,,,
0,,,,,État général,Élément,Observations,,,,
1,,,,,État d'usage,Faux plafond / éclairage,Dalle faux plafond manquante,,,,
Éclairage fonctionnel,,,,,,,,,,,
2,,,,,,Bureau / Faux plafondBureau / Faux plafondBureau / Faux plafond / éclairage,,,,,
Bureau / Faux plafond / éclairageBureau / Faux plafond / éclairage,,,,,,,,,,,
0,Bureau,,,,,,,,,,
1,Sol,État d'usage,Tâches au sol,,,,,,,,
2,Bureau / SolBureau / SolBureau / Sol,,,,,,,,,,
Bureau / SolBureau / Sol,,,,,,,,,,,
0,,,,,État d'usage Porte qui ne ferme pas,,,Porte d’accès entrepôt,,,
```

Also I tried transforming the .csv to .txt but removing the "," is a big problem.

Comment: Do all the CSVs have same exact columns?

Comment: No they are all different

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pandas` library:

```
import pandas as pd
csv_files = [...]
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in csv_files])
combined_csv.to_csv( "combined.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: this solution doesn't work, it's not in order and it adds a lot of rows/columns

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

path = # path to the file
files = glob.glob(path + "*.csv")

dfs = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in files]
df = pd.concat(dfs)  

df.to_csv("15526-Afjuej_djquz_assemble.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: this solution doesn't work, it's not in order and it adds a lot of rows/columns